# How can I make the vscode gui visible?

Tags: visual-studio-code, centos7

[image]

I am using CentOS 7.7.1909 version.
I installed vscode via yum, the window pops up but nothing comes up like the screenshot. What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

Try running it from the command line with the following flag:

```
code --disable-gpu
```

The Electron shell used by Visual Studio has trouble with some GPU hardware acceleration.